# Suppose we have a number $p>1$, then show that p is a prime if and only if $\sigma(p)=p+1$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

This is what I have written: is it this correct?

We can prove this by simply saying that if $p$ is a prime number, then the only divisors of $p$ are $p$ and $1$. So we have $\sigma(p)=p+1$.

Conversely, if we have $\sigma(N)=N+1$, this tells us the only divisors of $N$ are $N$ and $1$, which makes it a prime number.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  In general $\sigma (n)≥n+1$ with equality only for primes.

Comment: What is $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine.

When writing out a proof at this level I might spell out more explicitly the fact that 1 and N always divide N so that $\sigma(N)\geq N+1$ in general rather than just saying "This tells is the only divisors are 1 and N" without explanation.

Once you move to proofs where details like that aren't the crux it's okay (and recommended) to leave them out.